# jquery ui autocomplete with database not working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, pdo, autocomplete

I'm trying to build a simple input form with jquery ui autocomplete where a customer can find their brand of cell phone and after choosing one they will go to the next page to complete a form so they can get an estimate.

The only thing is I can't seem to get the autocomplete function to work. I have made a simple database with only one column named `merken` and I have been using a tutorial from the net to access this database with a PHP script. When I used the old `mysql_fetch_array` I could access the database but only got one item returned and so I updated to the PDO function and no result is returned.

This is the code that I have been using and got zero results.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'myuser';
$dbpass = 'mypass';
$dbname = 'autocomplete';

try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$return_arr = array();

if($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM merken LIKE :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term", $ac_term);
    $result->execute();

    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $row_array['value']= $row['merken'];

        array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
    }
}

$conn = null;

echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Any help is much appreciated since I have been stuck on this feature for a couple of days now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your where statement? Not:

```
SELECT * FROM merken LIKE :term
```

but:

```
SELECT * FROM merken WHERE column_name LIKE :term
```

Comment: Daimos thank you so much that did the trick indeed. Now I get the whole list when searching in brands. I'm going to add this explanation to my php learning book.